# PhantomJS page breaking in tables adds extra space

Tags: javascript, html, css, phantomjs

I'm having some trouble with PhantomJS where it is adding an unwanted space to the rows of my table following a page break when I attempt to render my page into a PDF. The size of the unwanted space appears to be related to the amount of space that the table row had to be moved to avoid splitting it across two pages. I've included an image of the issue:

[image: Image of spacing issue]

I've re-colored the table so that in the pdf it is more clear which elements are which. In the problematic right hand column, the colors are as follows:

Yellow is the `<td>` element. That element contains a `<div>`, which is cyan. That contains two inline block `<div>`s which are dark blue, and red.

What could be causing this extra space to appear, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: I was having problems with phantom not loading all my css files. Check the `<head>` block to see if all your css tags are there.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not the issue, all of my css is in place.